# @Input in Angular 4

Tags: angular, input, angular2-template, angular2-components

I am new to Angular 4.As per my understanding, @Input is used to pass values to a component. But when I use it as mentioned below it doesn't work.

```
my-file.component.html
    <h1 [user] = "currentuser"></h1>

my-file.component.ts
    @Input() 
    user : string;
```

Comment: `<h1` is not a component

Comment: As Angular mentioned. You need to add it to a component selector, selectors are described in tour or heros part 3: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means you can pass the string input into your my-file component itself not any HTML element (i.e. h1 in your case) within the component itself.

i.e. in the parent component you can call something like:

```
<my-file [user]="currentuser"></my-file>
```

Then this value of user will be available to be used within your my-file child component.

Comment: Then will you be kind enough to help me understand how did it work for a placeholder. The HTML is : <input type="search" [placeholder]="'Custom Placeholder'">

Comment: The .ts file :                                                                                                                 @Input('placeholder') searchText = 'Type your search';

Comment: `placeholder` is an existing attribute of the `input` element. `[placeholder]="searchText"` will bind the value of your component's `searchText` field to the component template's `input` element `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: Yes what @AndyLamb said. Sorry i've only just seen this again.

Answer (score 5):

In Component TS file you need to define `<my-file-comp [user]="currentUser"></my-file-comp>`

```
my-file.component.ts
    public @Input() currentuser: string

@Component({
  selector : 'my-file-comp',
  template: `Test Value : {{user}}`
})
class MyFileComp{
   public @Input() user: string

}

@Component({
    selector: 'testcmp',
    template : `<my-file-comp [user]="currentUser"></my-file-comp>`,
})

class TestComp{
    currentUser: string = "I Am user"; // Need to pass variable from here to my file component inside it's template
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('This if the value for user-id: ' + this.test);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Input() is used to import data from another component

Example get data in a-component.ts from b-component.ts
---------------------------------

receving data in user varibale :
a-component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Input() user;



b-component.html
<my-file [user]="anyValue"></my-file>

or 

if you are repeating a loop :
<my-file @ngFor="let item of items" [user]="item"></my-file>
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to explain how or why this answers the question. Just pasting a block of code is generally not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `app.component.html`

```
<my-file [user]="currentUser"></my-file>
```

In your `my-file.component.ts`

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';

@Input() user;
```

After that you can use `currentUser` from `app.component` in the `my-file.component`

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding itself is wrong . @Input() property is used for import data from another component. Eg: That another component you can export also otherwise it will not work.